# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, c#-2.0, asp.net-4.0

i search a lot but didn't find what i want this question is ask by many users here but i didn't find my solution so i ask this question.

- i have page in which i have **Assign** and **withdraw** button which
  is used to Assign and withdraw **device id** for the selected **group
  id** (group id fetch from dropdownlist) from one list-box to another
  that part is completed
- Now when i add another device id for the same    group id i need to
  append that updated record and show it in    listbox2.

here is my code:

```
 string queryString1 = "select device_id from device_group_master where group_id='" + ddlGroupName.SelectedValue.ToString() +"'";
                            SqlDataAdapter newdataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString1, con);
                            SqlCommandBuilder newcommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(newdataAdapter);

                            newdataAdapter.Fill(ds1, "table");
                            if (ds1.Tables["table"].Rows.Count != 0)
                            {
                                if (ds1.Tables["table"].Rows[0][0].ToString() == "0")
                                {
                                    string queryString2 = "update DEVICE_GROUP_MASTER set DEVICE_ID='" + device.ToString() + "', NOT_EXCLUDE_DEVICE_ID='" + enable + "' where GROUP_ID='" + ddlGroupName.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                                    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(queryString2, con);
                                    update.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string append;
                                    append = ds1.Tables["table"].Rows[0][0].ToString();                                        
                                    append += ","+ device;
                                    string queryString2 = "update DEVICE_GROUP_MASTER set DEVICE_ID='" + append.ToString() + "' where GROUP_ID='" + ddlGroupName.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                                    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(queryString2, con);
                                    update.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type**- this error suggest that there is some conversion issue for e.g. if your column is having a datatype as varchar and you are trying to read int value from that then it will throw this error

Comment: i know about the error. i m trying to insert int, int in my database column or u can say i want to append data in a column where i already have some int value

Comment: but how can you set **DEVICE_ID=append.ToString()** if your DEVICE_ID column is an int ?